# Maths - Android Program

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm currently making a basic maths application in Android.
Program will print on `std output` the following text: 2 + 2 = ?

User inputs a value by pressing a button and the program will then displays 2 + 2 = 4.

I got that part to work using buttons and `setText` but I want to have 10 different addition questions on the same activity.

My problem is that I can't press the same button again because it simply brings up the `TextView`.

Do you think drawing numbers on a canvas woukd be a better approach?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    add = 4;
    display.setText("2 + 2 =" + add);
}
```

Comment: can't you use an `EditText` for the answer and use a "submit" button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the activity of the button with a flag called `answered` or something to that effect.  Assuming you want to cycle through your questions:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if (!answered)
  {
    add = getNextAnswer();
    display.setText(getCurrentQuestion() + add); 
  } else
    display.setText(getNextQuestion());
  answered=!answered;
}
```

This changes based on how you're storing/generating your questions

Answer (score 0):

To answer your only question: if you want to have very pretty numbers and operators, then sure, draw them into a canvas.  Otherwise, you lose nothing from using text, and you gain some ease (of adaptability to different screens, of doing the 'drawing', of styling in XML.)

To respond to the vague bulk of your post: are you perhaps irritated by how `.setText()` erases what you'd previously written to the display?  Then take a look at the `.append` method, and others that may be useful from [TextView's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).  A basic use: `display.append("\nthis is on the next line");`  You may at this point also want a ScrollView in your XML layout.

Comment: i apoligize about not being clear, i mean when i click button 4 it shows the answer and lets say i want to display another question which i got to work using another textview i cannot press the button 4 again because it simply loads the prevous question. Trust me i know its vaugue but im a begginer so i dont know how else to break it down.